# html5 audio tag is not playing audio

Tags: html, wordpress, audio

I am trying to embed a html5 audio tag in my web page here is the code.

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="http://thearabiclab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arabic-word-meeting.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="http://thearabiclab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arabic-word-meeting.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

path of both the files mp3 and ogg are correct, the issue is when the page loads first time it will display the player correctly but suddenly it will transform into something like the image below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkjrql4vzr3pkrh/Screenshot%202015-07-05%2015.12.56.png?dl=0

Please help to resolve this issue.

thanks

Comment: your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7tvtLsba/ you probably have something else on your page that breaks things up.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned code working fine for me..

What you can do to debug it first make a separate HTML file copy and paste the code, check if it working or not. It's looking sure... some conflict with your Js or jQuery.